# String to float conversion

Tags: java, string-formatting

I need to convert a string with value 12.10 to a float value without losing the zero. How can I achieve this in Java.

Answer (score 2):

if you aren't worried about memory then

```
    String str = "12.00";
    BigDecimal bd=  new BigDecimal(str);
    System.out.println(bd);//12.00
```

Answer (score 1):

a) It makes no sense to store trailing zeroes in a float.

b) 12.1 will not map precisely to a floating point value (although this may not be immediately apparent)

Answer (score 1):

**From Bloch, J., Effective Java, 2nd ed, Item 48:**

> The `float` and `double` types are
>   particularly ill-suited for monetary
>   calculations because it is impossible
>   to represent 0.1 (or any other
>   negative power of ten) as a `float` or
>   `double` exactly.
>
> For example, suppose you have $1.03
>   and you spend 42c. How much money do
>   you have left?
>
> ```
> System.out.println(1.03 - .42);
> ```
>
> prints out `0.6100000000000001`.
>
> The right way to solve this problem is
>   to use `BigDecimal`, `int` or `long`
>   for monetary calculations.

Example:

```
BigDecimal price =  new BigDecimal("12.10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.text.DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double floatval = fmt.parse("12.10").doubleValue();
String sval = fmt.format(floatval);
```